# Making an App with PhoneGap that operates without internet

Tags: ipad, cordova

I want to create a small App that just shows WebPage with link, video Playing and PDF Documents. The problem is that I expect the app to open Video, PDFs etc without accessing internet.

So, when I click on video, it should play even without internet.

Is it possible to do this in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as they are in a format that the device can handle in the browser directly, you should be fine. A good way to think of PhoneGap is like an enhanced web browser.

You should be able to put the files into the resources, and PhoneGap should be able to access them completely fine. It essentially works by using the `file:///` scheme, so you can probably try making something like you'd want to put on the iPad, and try it on your computer. If it doesn't work on there, it likely won't work on the iPad either.

In terms of video files, you'd probably want to use an .mp4, as these should be natively supported by the iOS WebView.

Now that being said, if you're trying to get your app in to the AppStore, you may want to look into the Apple User Interface guidelines. For example section 12.3 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) states that apps that are `... a collection of links, may be rejected`.

You may also find the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamie, for answering the question. That's a big relief.